# subdirectory calls root index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory

On my website I've a E-commerce CMS which includes all template files and rendering functions. I'm trying to create some static pages outside the CMS (not intended to make static content) but using the same template. For this I've created a static page structure in a subdirectory but want the URL to call the root index.php for rendering.

Here is the site structure:

```
/index.php
/subdir/fr/mypage1.html
/subdir/fr/mypage2.html
/subdir/en/mypage1.html
/subdir/en/mypage2.html
```

the index.php code:

```
...
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/subdir_fr/')!==false){
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/subdir_fr/'.end(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
        }
...
```

so calling the example.com/subdir_fr/mypage1.html it will call the root index.php
same if I type example.com/subdir_en/mypage1.html, I'll manage which file to include in my PHP file.
I absolutely need the URL to be kept, I absolutely don't want a redirection.

Thank you for help

Comment: Your htaccess is most likely configured to return existing files. When it does not find a file it will call ur index.php. So u have to name ur static html differently then the actual url u want to open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: it's what I want, if file not found, return root index.php but it's not actually what it's doing. example.com/subdir_fr/mypage1.html returns a file not found error and I want it to call the root index.php